# Paypal IPN changing data?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the Paypal IPN to update the `status` of an order to `2`. Once we deliver the order, we manually change it to `3`, but then sometimes it goes back to `2` on it's own (note that until it's `2`, we can't even see it in our order panel).

Does the Paypal IPN update it again? What's causing this?

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";


$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strpos($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

...
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like IPN is updating it again, but there are a number of a reasons that could be happening.

If your IPN script has a problem with it that keeps from fully completing then PayPal will send the IPN again until it receives a 200 response back from your server.  It's possible you have some sort of a syntax error or something that happens after the majority of the code runs.  So the code runs, updates your system to a 2, but then fails after that, so PayPal sends the IPN again.  Log into your PayPal account and check your IPN History to see if that could be what's going on.

Another reason could be if the original payment was pending for some reason.  When IPN hit with the pending status it updates to 2, then it hits again once the payment status updates and updates it to a 2 again.

These are just a couple of ideas of what could possibly be happening.  I would recommend adding some logging to your IPN script of some sort.  A log file, database log, or even an email to yourself so you can see if it's running more than once for the same transaction.  From there you could figure out exactly why it's running more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You know those times where you feel really dumb after asking a question? This is one of those times.

I added `AND 'status' = '0'` to the query so even if it does check it later, it won't do anything.

Comment: You still want to figure if (and then why) it's hitting your URL multiple times.  If it's doing that it means your server is not returning a 200 response to PayPal.  If that continues for too long they will disable your IPN feature because it wastes server resources.